# Remove a flag from C++FLAGS in Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I've got a Makefile that includes another makefile that sets a lot of defaults. I can't edit the included makefile and I'd like to change the value of C++FLAGS in my makefile even though it is set in the included makefile. Specifically, I'd like to remove the optimization flag from C++FLAGS whenever debug=1.

I tried the following:

```
C++FLAGS=$(filter-out -O3,$(C++FLAGS))
```

Which fails with the following error:

```
Recursive variable `C++FLAGS' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
```

It seems like doing something like this should be possible, anybody know the secret?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
C++FLAGS:=$(filter-out -O3,$(C++FLAGS))
```

The `:=` assignment *immediately* evaluates the rvalue and this should therefore work. `=` on the other hand has delayed expansion semantics (i.e. the `C++FLAGS` will expand whenever the lvalue gets used, which leads to recursion).